# Need to display matching records from 2 seperate tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables, one with Vendors and one with Products. There is a foreign key shared between the 2 tables which is a Code. I need a command that displays which vendors have codes matching the products table. There fore the data displayed will tell us Which Vendors provide products and which vendors do not. I only need to display the ones that do provide products.

```
SELECT * FROM vendor where V_CODE = V_CODE FROM product;
```

I have a pseudo code logic here which is what I am looking for. I want SQL to display All vendors who have a matching V_CODE in both the vendor and products table.

```
SELECT * FROM vendor where V_CODE = V_CODE FROM product;
```

This code does not compile because FROM is not in a valid position

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: You should reread your notes on joins.

Comment: [Joins (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-2017) & [13.2.10.2 JOIN Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) (Search engines are your friend :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `join` with proper syntax

```
SELECT * FROM vendor join product
on vendor.V_CODE = product.V_CODE
```

Comment: That did it Thank you!